# How do I merge multiple materials on a 3d object into one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, blender

This is my first question here, and i'm very very new to 3D modelling so please be nice.

I'm not sure what i'm doing so the title probably isn't correct but essentially despite me making sure that my model is 100% one object in blender when I export it as a .obj and import it into photoshop for minor texture edits, my 3D model comes with several materials and I can't generate and edit the entire model's UV map in one single image, and I need the material to be a single .png image instead of many materials.

Pictures attached are:

- A screenshot of the model as I want it and want to export the material/texture file as
- What it appears like when imported into photoshop
- The many materials that I wish were just one

I'm using blender and photoshop for this, and while there is a dedicated blender stackexchange community, this seems more appropriate as the issues seemingly begin with photoshop. All I want is it to just export a single texture exactly how it looks in blender, but it all goes wrong when imported into photoshop.

[image: Model as I want it]

[image: Model as it appears when imported]

[image: List of materials]

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! Are you sure you didn't lose your `.mtl` file? This might be the reason why materials aren't displayed in PS. Why can't you generate and edit the entire model's UV map in one single image? Are you sure you're not mixing up materials and textures? Because you can't merge materials (like you can't merge steel and frozen yogurt). What's the result you're after?

Comment: Hi, I have an .mtl file but i'm not sure how to import it into photoshop. Does it automatically import with the .obj? Essentially the result i'm after is a UV map which I have figured out how to generate but I can only generate a blank UV map, in blender it looks exactly how I want it but I cannot figure out how to simply generate a UV map that is already filled in exactly as it appears in blender (The top image.) Is there some way to do this?

Comment: `.mtl` should load automatically (should be in the same folder, same name). And sure, it depends on your texture needs. It's difficult to understand from the screenshot, those textures look like flat colors? If yes you can make a texture with these colors, place your UVs into those color blocks. If those are precisely placed textures, you'll need to rebake those to new uvs, that's more complicated. Once again, on the screenshot I can only see an object with different materials.